# Server always return 503 (Service Unavailable) in slow request (FastAPI + Vue)

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, request, timeout, fastapi

thank you guys for supporting me
Currently I'm using a FastAPI server in Python and VueJS in client side.
I had an API to call for starting a virtual EC2 machine in AWS. This work took so much time.
So my request was slow, and it always return `503 code` to client, although in server side it still return `200 OK`
[image]

[image]

Do you guy have any idea about this stuff?

How can I config to wait such a slow query (timeout)?

Comment: Which library are you using for your requests? In Axios for ex there is a timeout parameter which can be set

Comment: @jeremycastelli 
I am using Axios for requesting, I will check it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try add cors for domain frontend in backend fastAPI

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "https://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nam, it was ready in my project, so this solution may not work.